# Horizontal parallax effect to text on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I sort of got it working. I believe I am not understanding the javascript correctly.

I took this from another thread, however it isn't behaving quite the way I am trying to achieve. I see the variables are a math equation that bases the movement on the window height.

1. How can I manipulate the equation so that I can control "Some cool text."'s initial position (if you notice on load it takes the correct position, and then on scroll it gets moved by JS) to stay where I want it?
2. What controls the speed and intensity of the movement and how can I manipulate that?

I believe I am just not understanding the syntax that controls all these variables, can you point me in the right direction for some reading to understand these specific variables? Thank you. :D

https://jsfiddle.net/codingcrafter/kv9od1ju/22/

```
/* Custom Horizontal Scrolling Parallax */
.hero-two {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 500px;
}

h1 {
   -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.1rem;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
   color: #fff;
   font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Times New Roman !important;
   font-weight: 900;
}

.para-ele {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 5rem;
}

#hero-first {
  left: 75%;
  top: 15%;
}

#hero-second {
  left: -32%;
  bottom: 10%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

<div class="container">
  <div class="hero-two">
    <h1 id="hero-first" class="h1 para-ele">
      Some cool text.
    </h1>
    <h1 id="hero-second" class="h1 para-ele">
      Some boring text.
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $horizontal = $('#hero-first');

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var s = $(this).scrollTop(),
      d = $(document).height(),
      c = $(this).height();

    scrollPercent = (s / (d - c));

    var position = (scrollPercent * ($(document).width() - $horizontal.width()));

    $horizontal.css({
      'left': position
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to move the text from left to right or right to left?

I have done something similar to your issue but I used jQuery to handle the scroll effect.

If you are going to use the code below you will need to wrap the text within a element with the class **Introduction**

As the page scrolls the  element will append the styles dynamically to the element.

```html
<h1 class="introduction">

WE ARE A <br><span class="d">DIGITAL</span><br>PARTNER

</h1>
```

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    $(".introduction").css({
        transform: "translateX(-" + wScroll / 23 + "%)"
    })
});
```

Demo: https://guide-nancy-64871.netlify.com/
When page is scrolled the header text moves to the left.

Read more on css transform: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: translate! i almost forgot that existed. this works perfectly. my goal is to get each element to  move like that and i think this is a great start for me.